# Drawing line always ends with Circle

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use CustomPainter to make a board that i can draw on , i added logic to draw the line , and also the circle , but i didn't figure out why is always ending each line with a circle , i want the line to be normal line , here is a picture of what line looks after drawing

[image]

here is where i store the positions

```
  final _points = <Offset>[];
```

and this is the paint

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO:  initState
    super.initState();
    _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 8;
  }
```

here is my widget

```
  body: Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
                onPanDown: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    _points.add(details.localPosition);

                  });
                },
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    _points.add(details.localPosition);
                  });
                },
                onPanEnd: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    _points.add(Offset.infinite);

                  });
                },
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: DrawingPainter(_points, _paint),
                  child: Container(),
                ))),
```

and this is the paint methode on the class i created DrawingPainter that extends from CustomPainter

```
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if ((i > 0 && points[i - 1].isInfinite == points[i].isInfinite) &&
          points[i].isInfinite == points[i + 1].isInfinite) {
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], _paint);
      } else if (!points[i].isInfinite && points[i + 1].isInfinite) {
        canvas.drawCircle(points[i], 8, _paint);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: could you include `_paint` config inside `DrawingPainter`?

Comment: i have updated my post , the _paint is on the main widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
canvas.drawCircle(points[i], 8, _paint);
```

`drawCircle` get `radius` to draw it, so you `_paint` strokeWidth is `8` so your drawCircle's radius should be `4` to draw Circle equal to your stroke, so change it to this:

```
canvas.drawCircle(points[i], _paint.strokeWidth/2, _paint);
```